# Kivy as connecting to a database?

Tags: php, python, mysql, kivy

I read that you can connect to a database "mysql" data Kivy with `pymysql`, I tested with `pymysql` and `mysqldb` and work very well, but the problem is to compile a `apk`, the program even starts, and the problem was to remove these libraries because the program works, but to compile and install it on the mobile stops working.

So I see that as yet there is no API to connect, I wonder if I can do mediating php, php connect to and get Kivy

Comment: I had issues getting MySQLdb to build and run, but PyMySQL works for me (via SQLAlchemy). But as brousch said, you really should be using an API if you're connecting to an external server. Only use pymysql if you're connecting to a server on a local corporate network, or if you're running MySQL directly on your Android device (i.e. with Debian Kit).

Answer (score 2):

For a mobile app, you should generally not be connecting directly to a remote database. You should be providing an API that sits in front of your database. This may be what you mean by "mediating php". Then in your Kivy app you can use the built in [URL request feature](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.network.urlrequest.html) or include Requests.